# Atomic Design, organism in organism?

Tags: responsive-design, user-experience, atomic-design

Atomic Design seem to be an interesting methodology to construct an UX structure. But can one organism contain others organisms ?

Answer (score 5):

According to this React implementation of Atomic Design:

> An organism is a group of atoms, molecules and/or other organisms:

https://github.com/diegohaz/arc/wiki/Atomic-Design

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is completely okay to include an organism inside another organism.

An `organism` is actually: A group of atoms, molecules and/or other organisms.